# How to remove /?nonamp=1 URL nignx wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I want to remove my WordPress site ***/?nonamp=1*** URL part.Because wordprss shows 400 errors for this pages. Googlebot regularly access these URL's. I want to redirect above url parameter to clean url. My URL permalink structure like bellow.

*https://www.example.com/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html*

I have created following nginx rewrite rule. But it's not working in my situation. When I debug nginx it shows

*^(.*/)/?nonamp=1$" does not match*

This is my rewrite rule.

> rewrite ^(.*/)/?nonamp=1$ $1 permanent;

Could you please tell me what the error in this rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything from the `?` onwards, is the query string and is not part of the [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) used by `rewrite` and `location` to match regular expressions.

If you just want to redirect anything with a `nonamp=` argument to the basic URI with any arguments removed, test the `$arg_nonamp` variable with an `if` block.

For example:

```
if ($arg_nonamp) {
    return 301 $uri;
}
```

Comment: Dear @RichardSmith My problem fixed by your suggestion. Thanks a log.